# How to display List results in JSP Page?

Tags: java

I Have a class that find Google search results. And i have a JSP page that i want to show the results in. But i can't do it.

Heres my UrlOku class :

```
 public static void GetUrl() {
      final String keyword = "emre varol";
      final String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+keyword;

      try {
        final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Element row: document.select("div[class=g]")) {
            final String title = row.select("div[class=TbwUpd NJjxre]").text();
            myList.add(title);

        }
      }
```

And heres my JSP page :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="urlpaket.Urloku" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp"></jsp:include>  
<%


if(session.getAttribute("username")==null){
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
%>
WELCOME ${username}
<%
Urloku oku = new Urloku();
oku.GetUrl();

%>
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="item">
        <tr>
  <td><c:out value="${item.title}" /></td>
</tr>
            </br>
</c:forEach>
```

And there is nothing in the welcome.jsp file.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Whats wrong with my question? 2 people vote negative. Can someone explain why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is myList variable available in you JSP? This needs to be set in pageContext before accessing it using ${myList}.
You can change the signature to `public static List GetUrl()`
and do something like this

```
Urloku oku = new Urloku();
List<String> myList = oku.GetUrl();
pageContext.setAttribute("myList ",myList );
```

Now it should be available.

Comment: Thank you for answer it worked. By the way , why 2 people vote negative to my question? I didn't want to do somethink wrong , im new in here :(

Comment: @emrevarol  Well not sure. Person to person depends. Anyways, if solution worked, please don't hold yourself to accept the answer. :)

Comment: The reason for negative vote could by before asking question directly you could search it and that could give you answer easily. :) To be honest I haven't gave negative vote. :)